# Input into 2D Array - C++ (issue with first row/column elements)

Tags: c++, arrays

I am writing a Tic-Tac-Toe game using C++. I created a 2D array for the board. The issue I am experiencing is when the user is picking a position to place their piece(X or O). When the user selects any letter in either the first row or first column, the program would just end. If, for example, the user picks the middle cell, it would correctly place the user's piece. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
char board[3][3] = { { 'A', 'B', 'C' }, { 'D', 'E', 'F' }, { 'G', 'H', 'I' } };
char player1 = 'X', player2 = 'O';



//displays board
void displayBoard() {
cout << "_________________" << endl;
cout << "|    |     |    |" << endl;
cout << "| " << board[0][0] << "  |  " << board[0][1] << "  |  "
        << board[0][2] << " |" << endl;
cout << "|____|_____|____|" << endl;
cout << "|    |     |    |" << endl;
cout << "| " << board[1][0] << "  |  " << board[1][1] << "  |  "
        << board[1][2] << " |" << endl;
cout << "|____|_____|____|" << endl;
cout << "|    |     |    |" << endl;
cout << "| " << board[2][0] << "  |  " << board[2][1] << "  |  "
        << board[2][2] << " |" << endl;
cout << "|    |     |    |" << endl;
cout << "|_______________|" << endl;
}

//check if game is over
bool checkStatus(char piece) {
bool over = false;
if ((board[0][0] == piece) && (board[0][1] = piece)
        && (board[0][2] = piece)) {
    over = true;
} else if ((board[1][0] == piece) && (board[1][1] = piece) && (board[1][2] =
        piece)) {
    over = true;
} else if ((board[2][0] == piece) && (board[2][1] = piece) && (board[2][2] =
        piece)) {
    over = true;
} else if ((board[0][0] == piece) && (board[1][0] = piece) && (board[2][0] =
        piece)) {
    over = true;
} else if ((board[0][1] == piece) && (board[1][1] = piece) && (board[2][1] =
        piece)) {
    over = true;
} else if ((board[0][2] == piece) && (board[1][2] = piece) && (board[2][2] =
        piece)) {
    over = true;
} else if ((board[0][0] == piece) && (board[1][1] = piece) && (board[2][2] =
        piece)) {
    over = true;
} else if ((board[0][2] == piece) && (board[1][1] = piece) && (board[2][0] =
        piece)) {
    over = true;
} else {
    over = false;
}
return over;
}

//gameplay
void game(char player1, char player2, bool current) {
bool turn = current; //true:player 1; false:player2
int row = 0, column = 0;
char position;
while (checkStatus(player1) != true && checkStatus(player2) != true) {
//player 1
    if (turn != false) {
        std::cout << "Player 1 Turn. Choose a Letter" << endl;
    }
//player2
    else if (turn != true) {
        std::cout << "Player 2 Turn. Choose a Letter" << endl;
    }
    displayBoard();
    std::cin >> position;
    position = toupper(position);
    switch (position) {
    case 'A':
        row = (position - 'A') / 3;
        column = (position - 'A') % 3;
        break;
    case 'B':
        row = 0;
        column = 1;
        break;
    case 'C':
        row = 0;
        column = 2;
        break;
    case 'D':
        row = 1;
        column = 0;
        break;
    case 'E':
        row = 1;
        column = 1;
        break;
    case 'F':
        row = 1;
        column = 2;
        break;
    case 'G':
        row = 2;
        column = 0;
        break;
    case 'H':
        row = 2;
        column = 1;
        break;
    case 'I':
        row = 2;
        column = 2;
        break;
    default:
        cout << "You didn't enter a correct letter! Try again\n";
        game(player1, player2, turn);
    }
    cin.clear();

//player X
    if (turn != false && board[row][column] != 'X'
            && board[row][column] != 'O') {
        board[row][column] = 'X';
        turn = false;
        checkStatus(player1);
        checkStatus(player2);
    }

//player O
    else if (turn != true && board[row][column] != 'X'
            && board[row][column] != 'O') {
        board[row][column] = 'O';
        turn = true;
        checkStatus(player1);
        checkStatus(player2);
    } else {
        cout << "Choose a valid cell!";
        game(player1, player2, turn);
    }
}
}

int main() {
int choice;
std::cout << "Welcome to Tic-Tac-Toe\n"
        "1 player game, enter 1\n"
        "2 player game, enter 2" << endl;
while (!(cin >> choice) || choice < 1 || choice > 2) {
    cout
            << "Bad input. Try again!\nfor a 1 player game, enter 1\nfor a 2 plater game, enter 2"
            << endl;
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n');
}

//two player game
if (choice != 1) {
    cout << "Tic-Tac-Toe: 2 Players" << endl;
    game(player1, player2, true);
} else {
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: First, why are you calling `game` recursively?   If I keep hitting the wrong key for input, your call stack piles up and up and up with calls.

Comment: I understand this is an issue, but right now I'm just assuming the user will enter a valid entry each time. I just would like it to print out the "X" or "O" into row/column 0. All it does is end the program when the user picks, lets say, board[0][0](corner cell).

Comment: Have you used the debugger?  If so, what is the path that the code takes when it gets out of the switch statement?

Comment: Funny thing about that, I am using eclipse to run my C++ code ( i am new to this language) and for some reason, the debugger will not launch. That is something I am actively looking to fix right now too. Just gives me an error.

Comment: Someone posted this: `row = (position - 'A') / 3; column = (position - 'A') % 3;` but I'm not sure i understand what this is intended to do.

Comment: Also, your code after the switch statement are duplicates, with the only difference being `X` and `O` and the value of `turn`.  Also, we need to see what state the board is when you call this function..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69097/discussion-between-user655321-and-paulmckenzie).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You fell pray to probably one of the oldest and most common programming error in c: `if (a==b)` vs `if (a=b)`

All the checks in `checkStatus` look like this:

```
if ((board[0][0] == piece) && (board[0][1] = piece) && (board[0][2] = piece))
```

when they should look like this:

```
if ((board[0][0] == piece) && (board[0][1] == piece) && (board[0][2] == piece))
```

Also, as far as game logic is concerned, you can condense the code after the switch statement to

```
if (board[row][column] != 'X' && board[row][column] != 'O') {
    if (turn)  board[row][column] = 'X';
    else       board[row][column] = 'O';       
    turn = !turn;
} else {
    cout << "Choose a valid cell!";       
}
```

this should produce the exact same behaviou.r